# Is it possible to send payment to another company with actions on google transactions?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm making a actions on google project that has transactions capabilities (I use the Google Pay method). The point of the action was for making transactions easy for local businesses in my area. When I was testing the transactions in sandbox mode, it occurred to me *where* the money would be going...

So, I assumed that it would by default because I own the project with my google account that the money would go to my account. However if that is true, that's not what I want. What I am trying to do is the money will go into the business's account *through* my action. If that doesn't make sense, here's **an example:**

1) A user uses my actions I have made (for simplicity lets just say its called test app)

2) The user says he wants to buy a 10 pack of pencils from the local supplies store " Buddies supplies " (name of the fictional store)

3) The order is fulfilled, the order is first collected from test app and then sent to Buddies supplies with the money sent to Buddies supplies. From there the rest is done by "Buddies Supplies".

So in essence, think of "test app" as sort of a middle man from customers to stores, kind of like uber eats or skip the dishes (if you have those in your area).

Does anyone know if this possible with actions on google? I tried going over the docs and I didn't see anything regarding this. If it's not, please just leave a simple "no" in the comments. That's better then having no answer!

Thanks for any suggestions or help, it's much appreciated!

**Note**: I have an implementation of my own of getting order information from user to retailers, its more the transaction end of things I'm wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with Google Pay transactions, you might have better luck using Stripe.

Stripe published a quickstart tutorial for Node.js and Express here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/express

Comment: I’m not having any trouble with Google pay, I’m just wondering if this is possible as a whole to basically send 1 payment to another account that’s not my own.

Answer (score 0):

Pay through the voice is already implemented by Square in the year 2012,and yes its already supported by the google too, and the money will be transferred through the google pay.

Check the link of the [square video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zoeiNBdPdo).

And to facilitate the voice-based tx. just follow the [link](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/) and you can do it